# Bootstrap pop effect not calling

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently the bootstrap isn't working, and has no errors related with pulling the Bootstrap and CSS files

HTML button

```
<button style="margin-left: 5%" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

The Javascript onclick call

```
<script>
function pop()
{
    (function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

}

</script>
```

Linking Files

````
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>```
````

Comment: Any error on the console

Comment: everything is looking good, use latest bootstrap cdn it will fix.

Comment: @Devi no console errors

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY I thought I was using the latest bootstrap